# How do I check if ranges:: algorithms like find_if returned a value?

Tags: c++, range, c++20, range-v3

For example, if I want to find the smallest element of a collection, but only the smallest **even** element, I'd like to call `ranges::min_element` with a filtered range like so:

```
using ranges::views::filter;
using ranges::min_element;
std::vector<int> vals{1,2,3,4,5};
auto minVal = min_element(vals | filter([](int next){return next % 2 == 0;}));
```

#### How do I check if the returned range is empty, and if not, access the value?

The same applies to other range algorithms like `ranges::find`, `ranges::find_if`, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot pass a temporary range into ranges algorithms.

This is because they will return a ranges iterator (possibly `ranges::end(rng)`) upon completion. If you pass a temporary, the returned iterator would be invalid; referencing a temporary. The ranges library detects this and returns a dummy sentinel, [`ranges::dangling`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/dangling) instead of an iterator.

The proper way to do this is to first compose your filtered range *then* call the algorithm.

```
std::vector<int> vals {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
auto even_vals = vals | filter([](int val){return val % 2 == 0;});
auto minVal = min_element(even_vals);
if (minVal == even_vals.end())
    std::cout << "no values\n";
else
   std::cout << *minVal; // prints "2"
```

#### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/HMrTXXsCNl2tYdYh)

Comment: This seems... so bad. Unnecessarily verbose and it gives a feeling of... *uncomposability*, which is the **exact opposite** of what ranges should be... Nonetheless, +1 for the good explanation.

Comment: @Enlico Sometimes, using GC can really simplify things, yeah.

Comment: @Deduplicator Immutability also does wonders.