# no match for operator * using min_element

Tags: c++, std-ranges, stdtuple, c++23, structured-bindings

Why can't I use operator * ? errors generated by gcc 14.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ranges>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    auto rng = views::iota(0, 3);
    const auto [a, b] = * ranges::min_element(views::cartesian_product(rng, rng));
    return 0;
}
```

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:7:29: error: no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<std::ranges::cartesian_product_view<std::ranges::iota_view<int, int>, std::ranges::iota_view<int, int> > >')
    7 |         const auto [a, b] = * ranges::min_element(views::cartesian_product(rng, rng));
      |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`std::ranges::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/min_element) "borrows" an iterator from the given range. In case of an rvalue `std::cartesian_product` (and any similar view), this would dangle in most circumstances since the lifetime of the `std::cartesian_product` would end after the iterator would be returned, so [`std::ranges::dangling`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/dangling) is returned. See this related question: [Why do std range algorithms return std::ranges::dangling for rvalue arguments instead of... well, just working?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65945216/5754656)

This would be safe in this case since the elements would be copied from before the `cartesian_product` rvalue's lifetime ends, but it prevents accidentally writing something like this:

```cpp
auto it = std::ranges::min_element(std::views::cartesian_product(rng, rng));
const auto [a, b] = *it;  // `it` is dangling, would be UB
```

The fix is to make it an lvalue:

```cpp
auto c = std::views::cartesian_product(rng, rng);
const auto [a, b] = *std::ranges::min_element(c);
```

Comment: Or to use `std::ranges::min`, since that's what OP actually needs.