How to filter vector before applying std::ranges::minmax_element?
When I try to filter std::vector elements before applying std::ranges::minmax_element by some reason I get the std::ranges::dangling which is hard to handle and can’t be used to get the access to the data found.
How can I combine filtering and member projection so that I could filter elements and find iterators to min/max?
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>

struct S {
    int n=0;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<S> v= { {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7} };
    
    const int excluder = 7;

    auto it_max = std::ranges::minmax_element( 
        v | std::views::filter([=](const auto& s) { return s.n != excluder ; }),
        std::less<int>(), &S::n
    ).max;

    std::cout << it_max->n;
}

Here is the DEMO.
The error message is:
<source>:20:24: error: member reference type 'std::ranges::dangling' is not a pointer; did you mean to use '.'?
   20 |     std::cout << it_max->n;
      |                  ~~~~~~^~
      |                        .
<source>:20:26: error: no member named 'n' in 'std::ranges::dangling'
   20 |     std::cout << it_max->n;
      |                  ~~~~~~  ^
2 errors generated.
Compiler returned: 1

Additionally, why I am getting std::ranges::dangling here? Shouldn’t this be more straightforward?

One way around this is to store the filtered range: https://godbolt.org/z/EYMKnM7E3

@SashSinha, thank you so much, worked like a charm! The questions are: (1) what changes when I store range to a temporary variable? Is it like now std::ranges::minmax_element has a chance to return iterator to a range that really exists unlike the situation in my code when it is just a temporary object? And (2) why I am getting std::ranges::dangling here? Because of the same reason?

@peter, you are wrong with the explanation here. The std::ranges::minmax_element returns not std::pair containing two iterators, but ranges::min_max_result<I>, which has min and max and if you look at my source code, I take this 'max' at the end of the line. This code works just fine if to filter is used and the issue comes with the filter. Would you explanation be correct, the code wouldn't be working even without filtering.

@SashSinha, aha, I see from the linked answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58400325/how-do-i-check-if-ranges-algorithms-like-find-if-returned-a-value) that my assumptions were correct. Thank you again!
